# Download PDF from URL with cookie and move to ADLS using Data Factory

Tags: http, pdf, cookies, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

The goal is to use Azure Data Factory to download a PDF file from a URL which requires passing a session cookie to authenticate to finally write the PDF file on ADLS2.

I'm trying to workaround Azure limitation of not allowing a cookie as a header when creating a Linked Service pointing at that URL.

So I used an HTTP activity which retrieves a JSON with some attributes similar to this one:

[image: Resulting HTTP JSON Response]

The *Response* attribute I guess what it contains is the PDF content as binary format, but not completely sure.

I managed to write that JSON response as a JSON file to ADLS Gen2 with a Copy Data Activity using an external Template file as Source dataset:

[image]

Using Databricks, I can extract that Response value as a String (though I think this value represents a bytes string), but I do not know how to create a PDF file back to ADLS Gen2 based on that String shown in the image.

[image]

Im using Python as programming language.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

I tried to convert the string got from Pyspark DF to Base64 (starting with JVBER) with the following code but by the time I open the PDF created, it is damaged:

```
import base64

# Encode binary string starting with %PDF to Base64
pdf_base64_str = base64.b64encode(bytes(pdf_content_string, "utf-8"))
pdf_bytes = base64.b64decode(pdf_base64_str, validate=True)

# Write base64 PDF string to a PDF file
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as pdf:
    pdf.write(pdf_bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Copy Activity` with source as `HTTP` binary dataset and sink as `Blob storage`
`binaryFile` giving extension `.pdf`.

Below is the configuration in source dataset.

[image]

**Source dataset** : binary dataset having **HTTP** linked service.

**Request method** : **GET**

**Additional headers**: `header_name:header_value`.

Here, i've given

```
Cookie:__cf_bm=gy6iVNE912dklRuTCuVND8kf45d_.uv8TBFko95CBeI-1693287559-0-AdfWdItK4W8BPAh4VKpEo/C4XlP06+4cUyaHva1/y556jLac0VfsYnkQuIN8z+KnWQBmEyds/7/fuDZmfMzjA3I=
```

[image]

Add your pdf url in **Base URL** option.

I am using below url to get pdf.

```
https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf
```

[image]

This is the result in postman using above url.

Below is the configuration in sink.

[image]

After running copy activity you will get file in your blob storage.

[image]

In storage account.
[image]

Since, you can not view pdf in storage account, download and verify it.

[image]